# how to find in a dataframe the highest ratio between the values of 2 columns without losing track of the code associated to those rows?

Tags: python, dataframe

I need 2 lists (one for highest teacher-student ratio and the other for the lowest ratio) which contain the codes of the 10 districts of the schools that have the highest and lowest teacher / student ratio, respectively.
This is the dataset, the columns i need to work on are underlined in red.
I need to calculate the 10 highest value from dataframe.students/dataset.teachers but i also have to associate to every ratio the dataset.district row.
I tried but i can't get around this.
Please help me.
[image: This is the dataset]

Comment: you may add a new column for teacher-to-student ratio, and use `nlargest` or `nsmallest`. Check this for details about `nlargest` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html